# "failed to open stream: Permission denied" after 777 my entire app

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5

I'm growing several grey hairs trying to work this one out.

All of a sudden in my Laravel project, I can't upload any files to my symlinked public/storage directly as it's complaining about permissions.

I then 777'ed every single file in the app (I know, I know), and it's still complaining about permissions. I've also run `composer dump-autoload`, which never seems to do anything but I thought I'd give it a go anyway.

Does anyone know what else I can try? I can verify everything is 777, so I can't see why any permissions would fail...

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. hint: recursive `chown` and `chmod` will not follow symlinks... and if I'd had to guess, I'd assume that a parent directory or the symlink destination cannot be listed; where `chmod +x` helps.

Comment: Some things that might help determine the cause: The error stack trace, the code that caused it, Webserver (apache/nginx?), server config (followsymlinks enabled?),  OS name/version, Laravel version, PHP version

Comment: May you share the code you´re using to save and get the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SE Linux might be a possible culprit, because the policies change in some cases, eg. when there are broken modules, it will mess up. that would be `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1` (if this should throw an error, manually deleting the broken modules is the only thing that helps).

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but it looks like it'd be really helpful for the right person, so I'm giving it a tick :)

Comment: Does SE linux do anything helpful? I've only known it to conflict with things. (This is sort of a rhetorical question).

Comment: @Chipster it generally provides proper isolation, where everything has a security context. once having defined the policies, it just runs. so far it only happened once to me that I had broken modules, due to some half-done `redis` uninstall.

Comment: @MartinZeitler so it's an antivirus of sorts?

Comment: @Chipster https://people.redhat.com/tcameron/Summit2012/SELinux/cameron_w_120_selinux_for_mere_mortals.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Gah, sorry guys, this was a bit of a red herring.

777'ing everything wasn't working because the uploaded files were being set to 644 (so my manual 777 was only being applied to files that already existed)

For future reference, if anyone's using Laravel and a queued job can't access a 644 file, set the file to 664 immediately after upload (`apache` owns the uploaded file, but `www-data` (or `ec2-user`) is the one trying to access when queued).

Comment: this hints for having the wrong web-server user set somewhere, because `apache` and `www-data` are ordinary the equivalent user, it's just two different usernames being used by different Linux distributions.

Comment: just checked the source code, but couldn't find the username anywhere ... changing `http.conf` to make the server run as `www-data` instead of `apache` might also fix it... because this should result in a file owned by `www-data`. there has to be some reason, why the usernames aren't consistent... most likely it comes from some composer dependency, which had been built with another distribution, therefore the other username.

Comment: You're almost certainly right @MartinZeitler - in my case I'd say it's because Laravel itself runs as `apache` most of the time, but when it runs jobs off the queue it's using whatever user started the queue (or Supervisor). 664 instead of 644 is fine for me, but making the server run as `www-data` would work just as well.